# Name tag is changing when using th:field

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to make a simple form with thymeleaf that only uses some of the data, the rest are shown to the user normally. But I got stuck on that thymeleaf th:field changes the HTML tag - name. The consequence of this is that the form is not working properly - I can check a few options. **I want to be able to select only one option.**  Here is the code I wrote:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="text-center" th:object="${post}">
            <h2 th:text="*{title}">Title</h2>
            <div>
                <label th:text="*{shortDescription}">Short description</label>
            </div>
            <form action="#" method="post" th:action="@{/post/{id}(id=${post.id})}" class="mt-5">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                        <input type="radio" id="option1" name="option" class="custom-control-input" value="1" th:field="*{option1}">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" th:text="*{option1.getOptionValue() + ' - ' + option1.getVoteAmount()}"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                        <input type="radio" id="option2" name="option" class="custom-control-input" value="2" th:field="*{option2}">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" th:text="*{option2.getOptionValue() + ' - ' + option2.getVoteAmount()}"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                        <input type="radio" id="option3" name="option" class="custom-control-input" value="3" th:field="*{option3}">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" th:text="*{option3.getOptionValue() + ' - ' + option3.getVoteAmount()}"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Vote</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this is my controller:

```
@PostMapping("/post/{id}")
    public String updateRoom(@ModelAttribute("id") Integer id, String option1, String option2, String option3 , Model model) {
        Post post = postModel;
        postService.increaseVoteCounter(option1, option2, option3, post);
        model.addAttribute("post", postModel);
        return "detailsPost";
    }
```

And PostModel class is looks like this:

```
public class PostModel {
    private String username;
    private String option1;
    private String option2;
    private String option3;
    private String shortDescription;
    private String title;

    //getters and setters
}
```

And finally how it's looks like in browser:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7gBp.png)

Comment: maybe you can try to mark the line where your error is and what you would expect instead to make your problem clearer

Comment: Changed - I want to be able to select only one option but thymeleaf (th:field) is changing name tag in radio form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`th:field` always changes the **name** and **id**

You shouldn't use it here

[read more about this](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#inputs)